# Fitting experimental data by using ParametricNDSolveValue and NonlinearModelFit

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, fitting, parametric-functions

I am a newcomer to Mathematica. 
Basically I just want to fit the data (enzyme kinetic data) shown below to a system of odes' by using NonlinearModelFit. The data, an 101x2 array, contains time in the first column and substrate concentration in the second. The model contains 4 species (`e[t]`, `es[t]`, `s[t]` and `p[t]`) and species `s[t]` is the one I want to fit the data to.   I get the following error:

> "The function value {<<1>>} is not a list of real numbers with 
>   dimensions {101} at {k1,k2,k3} = {4.`,3.`,1.`}". >>

Clicking on ">>" sends me to the basic NonlinearModelFit help page and I'm stuck there. 
The entire code is shown below.
Thanks if anybody can help.

Francesco

```
(*some data*)
data={{0, 4.9112}, {20., 4.75011}, {40., 4.43818}, {60., 4.28744}, {80., 
  3.97296}, {100., 3.86888}, {120., 3.69122}, {140., 3.59596}, {160., 
  3.22247}, {180., 2.85438}, {200., 2.81939}, {220., 2.88236}, {240., 
  2.49125}, {260., 2.55379}, {280., 2.33662}, {300., 2.34136}, {320., 
  1.88169}, {340., 1.9444}, {360., 1.73578}, {380., 2.04545}, {400., 
  1.74068}, {420., 1.70471}, {440., 1.37455}, {460., 1.35169}, {480., 
  1.29391}, {500., 1.35778}, {520., 1.1509}, {540., 1.18335}, {560., 
  0.846087}, {580., 0.957338}, {600., 0.855021}, {620., 
  0.727364}, {640., 0.886429}, {660., 0.817111}, {680., 
  0.748117}, {700., 0.569694}, {720., 0.77641}, {740., 
  0.661459}, {760., 0.561378}, {780., 0.56037}, {800., 
  0.500522}, {820., 0.322087}, {840., 0.44058}, {860., 
  0.359604}, {880., 0.31989}, {900., 0.278633}, {920., 
  0.318697}, {940., 0.150813}, {960., 0.427698}, {980., 
  0.364589}, {1000., 0.292937}, {1020., 0.27481}, {1040., 
  0.182754}, {1060., 0.349605}, {1080., 0.220416}, {1100., 
  0.149073}, {1120., 0.343196}, {1140., 0.173815}, {1160., 
  0.126286}, {1180., 0.145337}, {1200., 0.0800335}, {1220., 
  0.043485}, {1240., 0.399296}, {1260., 0.303941}, {1280., 
  0.161308}, {1300., -0.00255049}, {1320., 0.0296389}, {1340., 
  0.0919508}, {1360., 
  0.182537}, {1380., -0.0356638}, {1400., -0.140977}, {1420., 
  -0.0581143}, {1440., 0.115227}, {1460., 0.116371}, {1480., 
  0.118025}, {1500., 0.0556984}, {1520., 0.0831993}, {1540., 
  0.0135393}, {1560., 0.143889}, {1580., -0.0817538}, {1600., 
  0.0968327}, {1620., -0.0364522}, {1640., 0.0121839}, {1660., 
  0.0983604}, {1680., 0.144547}, {1700., -0.0734307}, {1720., 
  0.162225}, {1740., 0.100122}, {1760., 0.0253859}, {1780., 
  0.0108251}, {1800., 0.00686486}, {1820., -0.00330938}, {1840., 
  0.0277739}, {1860., 0.0291533}, {1880., 0.105267}, {1900., 
  0.174073}, {1920., 0.0668537}, {1940., -0.00195318}, {1960., 
  0.080458}, {1980., 0.0352437}, {2000., -0.0870161}};
(* Dimensions[data] {101, 2} *)

tmax = Max[data[[All, 1]]];

(* the model, k1, k2, k3 are the parameters *)

model = ParametricNDSolveValue[{e'[t] == (k2 + k3) es[t] 
- k1 e[t] s[t], es'[t] == -e'[t], s'[t] == k2 es[t] - k1 e[t] s[t],
    p'[t] == k3 es[t], e[0] == 0.001, s[0] == 5, es[0] == 0, 
   p[0] == 0}, s[t], {t, 0, tmax}, {k1, k2, k3}]

fit = NonlinearModelFit[data,model[k1, k2, k3][t], {{k1, 4.}, {k2, 3}, {k3, 1}}, t];
plotfit = Plot[model[k1, k2, k3] /. fit, {t, 0, tmax}];
plotdata = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]];
Show[plotfit, plotdata]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I am a newcomer to Mathematica also (use ver 9.0). I have a lot of mistakes when I try to reproduce this exemple. data = {{0, 4.9112}, {20., 4.75011}, {40., 4.43818}, {60., 4.28744}, {80., 3.97296}, {100., 3.86888}, {120., 3.69122}, {140., 3.59596}, {160., 3.22247}, {180., 2.85438}, {200., 2.81939}, {220., 2.88236}, {240., 2.49125}, {260., 2.55379}, {280., 2.33662}, {300., 2.34136}, {320., 1.88169}, {340., 1.9444}, {360., 1.73578}, {380., 2.04545}, {400., 1.74068}, {420., 1.70471}, {440., 1.37455}, {460., 1.35169}, {480., 1.29391}, {500., 1.35778}, {520., 1.1509}, {540., 1.18335}, {560., 0.846

Answer (score 12):

A minor change to `model` eliminates the error cited in the question.  (Replace `s[t]` by `s` in the final line of the code immediately below.)

```
model = ParametricNDSolveValue[{e'[t] == (k2 + k3) es[t] - k1 e[t] s[t],
    es'[t] == -e'[t], s'[t] == k2 es[t] - k1 e[t] s[t],
    p'[t] == k3 es[t], e[0] == 0.001, s[0] == 5, es[0] == 0, 
    p[0] == 0}, s, {t, 0, tmax}, {k1, k2, k3}];
```

Then, using `NonlinearModelFit` with better initial guesses yields a solution in seconds.

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[k1, k2, k3][t], {{k1, 6}, {k2, 3}, {k3, 3}}, t];
```

Finally, a corrected use of `fit` provides the desired result.

```
plotfit = Plot[fit[t], {t, 0, tmax}];
plotdata = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01]];
Show[plotfit, plotdata]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

For completeness, the fitted values of `{k1, k2, k3}` are

```
fit["BestFitParameters"]
{k1 -> 637.856, k2 -> 16540.4, k3 -> 80.546}
```

So, the initial guesses used above were not so good after all.  Evidently, they simply helped `NonlinearModelFit` to obtain a better start.  Other initial guesses, such as `{{k1, 12}, {k2, 6}, {k3, 6}}`, lead to different fitted values, here `{k1 -> 434.784, k2 -> 11248.8, k3 -> 80.5462}`, but with a final result indistinguishable to the eye from the plot above, even when displayed on a log scale.

Comment: The variability in parameter estimates depending on starting values is likely due to the model being overparameterized as `fit["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm` results in $\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1. & 1. & -0.765387 \\
 1. & 1. & -0.765385 \\
 -0.765387 & -0.765385 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$.  The estimators of `k1` and `k2` appear to be perfectly correlated with each other.

Comment: Thanks, @JimB.  This is a very useful observation.

Comment: Actually, setting `k1=700` and `k3=80` and fitting for `k2` results in a slightly smaller mean square error (`fit["EstimatedVariance"]`) and smaller AIC value.  That's not to say that the model is "bad" but simply that there isn't the right kind of data to estimate all three parameters.  Another indication of trouble is that the `fit["ParameterTable"]` shows huge standard errors for the full model.

Answer (score 5):

In case no better answer presents itself, this is a manual fit:

```
Manipulate[f[ti_] := Evaluate[model[k1, k2, k3] /. t -> ti];
 Show[lp, 
  Plot[Evaluate[model[k1, k2, k3]], {t, 0, tmax}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
  Graphics[Text[
    Sqrt[Total[
      Table[(f[data[[i, 1]]] - data[[i, 2]])^2, {i, 
        Length[data]}]]], {1500, 4}]]], {k1, 0.01, 40, 0.01}, {k2, 
  0.01, 80, 0.01}, {k3, 0.01, 40, 0.01}]
```

[image]

The goal is to minimise the numerical value displayed in the top right corner, this is the square root of the total of the square of the distances between the fit and the data points.